Local user in bootstrap.ini Microsoft Deployment Toolkit
Tell me how to specify a local user in bootstrap.ini.
I specify it in the following way, but it writes an error that there is no access. The WDS folder has full user rights
DeployRoot = \\server\WDS$
UserID=User
UserDomain=server
UserPassword=password


Dang, I used to know this answer as I ran a workgroup mode WDS instance. Have you tried omitting the UserDomain property?
